# Custom print on DNP DS620 cutting problems

Tags: linux, system, embedded-linux, cups, system.printing

Hi everyone i'm currently using a DNP DS620 on a raspberry pi and i'm doing some printing with the lpr commands like `lpr -P printername -o landscape picturename`
This gave me a picture of 4x6 inch (10x15cm)

So i'm able to order some prints with a command system (good yeah!) but i don't find any way to use the cutting option to have a double 2x6inch picture at the end.
I know that some Epson printers use the `source=DocFeedCut` command but it didn't work in my case.

So does everyone know the command for that or a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I contact someone from the driver's developer's team explaining my issue to him, this operation wasn't possible at that time on this device. They made some modifications to enable this kind of process on this new kind of printer, now it's possible.

Comment: would you mind explaining how you achieved the 2x6 cut?